# fill in tables by foreign keys using pdo. php

Tags: php, pdo

I want to fill in the table through the form, the form is primitive input and span, I will not attach the code. Tables:

Autopark

| id_auto | id_brend |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

Brends

| id_brend | brend |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

The tables are not all, the passage showed for understanding

```
 <?php
  session_start();
  include('config.php');
  if (isset($_POST['add_auto'])) {
    $brends = $_POST['brends'];
    $models = $_POST['models'];
    $fuels = $_POST['fuels'];
    $transmissions = $_POST['transmissions'];
    $kuzovs = $_POST['kuzovs'];
    $all_class = $_POST['all_class'];
    $colors = $_POST['colors'];
    $numb_engine = $_POST['numb_engine'];
    $cena = $_POST['cena'];
    $engine = $_POST['engine'];
    $produced = $_POST['produced'];
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM autopark WHERE numb_engine=:numb_engine");
    $query->bindParam(":numb_engine", $numb_engine, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
      echo "<script>sweet_true('error','такая почта уже зарегистрирована!');</script>";
    } if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
      $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO autopark(id_brend,id_model,id_class,id_kuzov,id_fuel,id_trans,engine,numb_engine,cena,engine,produced,id_color,image) VALUES (:brends,:models,:all_class,:kuzovs,:fuels,:transmissions,:engine,:numb_engine,:cena,:produced,:colors,:image)");
      $query->bindParam(":brends", $brends, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(":models", $models, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(":all_class", $all_class, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(":kuzovs", $kuzovs, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(":fuels", $fuels, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(":transmissions", $transmissions, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(":engine", $engine, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(":numb_engine", $numb_engine, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(":cena", $cena, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(":produced", $produced, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(":colors", $colors, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->bindParam(":image", $image, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $result = $query->execute();
      if ($result) {
        echo "<script>sweet_true('sucess','Регистрация прошла успешно!');</script>";
      } else {
        echo '<p class="error">Неверные данные!</p>';
      }
    }
  }
  ?>
```

I've tried everything, but I want values to be entered in the autopark table in the id_brend field

Comment: You're attempting to load the value of `$brends` into `id_brend`.  What is an example value of `$brends`?  What happens when you run the code?

Comment: You forgot to say what specific error or issue is occurring, or tell us about the debugging you've done so far.  "I tried everything", ironically, tells us nothing.